# How to minimize window when the taskbar icon is clicked?

Tags: qt, winapi

I have a Qt application with borderless window. So, I am creating my application window with CreateWindow() and then I have QWidget which uses the HWND.
Everything works fine, except that when the application is maximized and the Windows taskbar is set to auto-hide. In that case, if I click on the application icon, the program is not minimized. Even stranger is the fact that this only happens if the application is on my primary monitor. If it's on another monitor, everything works fine. Or, if the taskbar is not set to auto-hide, everything works fine on any monitor.
When the taskbar is set to auto-hide, on my primary screen the taskbar wasn't even showing up, so I am showing it with ShowWindow(hTaskbar, SW_SHOW). When it shows up, everything works when I click on the icons of other applications, so there must be something wrong with mine, but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: What window styles/extended styles did you use with `CreateWindow()`? What messages are you processing in your window procedure? Could you post a minimal example that reproduces the issue? This is a strange issue indeed...

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle WM_SYSCOMMAND and respond to SC_MINIMIZE.

[WM_SYSCOMMAND on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The thing is that I am not getting any WM_*. For some reason in that particular case my window isn't even getting notified that it should minimize...

Comment: @Amy Sorry to bring back an old post, but did you ever figure out your issue ?